# Grouped string constants with camel case values

Tags: java, enums, camelcasing

the goal is to have a grouped string constants with camel case values.
Ideally would be: `public enum Attribute {Measures, MeasuresLevel}`.
However its is not conform with the naming convention: constant names should be in uppercase. 
The following solutions looks like a data duplication:

```
public enum Attribute {
    MEASURES("Measures"), 
    MEASURES_LEVEL("MeasuresLevel");

    private final String value;

    Attribute(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Any alternatives, suggestions are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why don't just follow conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your enum

```
@Overwrite
public String toString(){
    String[] share = this.name().split("_");
    String camel = "";
    for(String s : share) {
        camel += s.charAt(0) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return camel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries provide utilities to convert to camelcase, like for instance `Guava` :

```
Stream.of(Attribute.values())
    .map(attr -> attr.toString())
    .map( attr -> CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, attr))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Have a look in the Guava [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat)